# NodeJs app files integrity security check

Tags: web-application, linux, integrity, source-code, node.js

What are the recommended methods or approaches to check NodeJs application (hosted on Linux server) files integrity check for security check?

There are usually huge number of files in `node_modules/`, so what approach should be followed to perform the required security check?

Comment: What's your threat model here? Attacker gaining access to the server and modifying node module files?

Comment: Very good question, there could be two types of threats. (1) We used an insecure module/library, which could be any 'X' module from inside the `node_modules/` folder. Which may infect or change any files. (2) Someone from inside the organization tries to change the specific files, in this case we are concerned with fewer file but not `node_modules/` folder.

Comment: for #2 i like `git status`; simple. quick. reliable. #1 just needs vigilance.

Comment: :) like your simple approach for #2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're probably looking for is a Host Intrusion Detection System, or HIDS for short. These monitor the filesystem for changes and allow you to send alerts when something is modified, often either by email or by logging into a centralised system like Nagios.

The most common open-source HIDS I come across is [OSSEC](https://ossec.github.io/), and on the commercial side is [Tripwire](https://www.tripwire.com/). There's also [Verisys](https://www.ionx.co.uk/products/verisys). As far as I know all three of these are cross-platform.